# invoke webservice from another PC

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-applications, iis-6

i have a question how do you invoke a webservice from another PC i have a web service using IIS 6.1 in windows 7, the another PC has a IIS 6 in windows XP, the web services works in the localhost using a Web application, the only thing is now i am trying to invoke the web service from another Pc but don't now how to do that, one thing i have to mention is that i am not using Visual Studio for my web services and web application, i wrote all the code in a text block an using a web browser to see the web application, so the thing is the web application from the another pc is going to also be write in a text block , but i dont even don't now how to invoke.

when i invoke from the same Pc i used the next code from the web service, heres a simple example:

```
<%@ WebService language="C#" class="FirstService" %>
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using System.Web.Services;
    [WebService(Namespace="http://localhost/MyWebServices2/")]
    public class FirstService : WebService
        {

        [WebMethod]
    public double[][] Size(int X_1,int Y_1)
    {
        double [][] dime =  new double [X_1][];
        for (int r=0;r  < X_1; r++)
       {
        dime[r] = new double[Y_1];
        }
    return dime;
        }

       }
```

the web application used the next code:

```
<script runat="server">

    void loadFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x1=0,y1=0;
        x1= Convert.ToInt32(txtNum1.Text);
        y1= Convert.ToInt32(txtNum2.Text);
        FirstService mySvc = new FirstService();
        mySvc.Tamano(x1,y1);
        }
 </script>
```

is it necesari to change some part of my code? or all the change as to be mande from the web application of the another Pc?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "Url" property on the web service proxy object, "mySvc" to point to the
endpoint on the machine hosting the web service.

Example - `mySvc.Url = "http://machine:80//service...`

Please see the reference documentation - [Proxy reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soaphttpclientprotocol.aspx)